# Moving 2D collider with animation

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools, unity-game-engine

I was trying to create a basic cricket game. I created a batting animation, and added polygon collider. But I'm confused about adding collider to the moving bat in the animation.

[image]

Or are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: it's 2d @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 1):

you can move and resize the bat's polygon collider (make sure it's a 2d collider)
in the animation itself on every single frame of the animation.
simply click "add property" and look for your collider, once you added the collider to the animation you can start resizing him (size) and also moving it around (offset)

[image]